# How to add custom multiple select to highcharts legend?

Tags: highcharts, legend

I have a chart like [this](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic), where I have 29 series in a legend field. And I want to make it look better, so my question is: how can I add custom [multiple select](http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/) instead of selection which is provided by highcharts?

Comment: @ewolden still, I need an answer.

Comment: @ewolden I want it to look like [this](http://joxi.net/D2P5R99spE9plA) and my chart configuration is done similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/layout-horizontal/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to set enabled legend property to false, add html select list and write your own function to switch between series.

```
      function chose() {
      let selected = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
      chart.series.forEach((series) => {
        if (selected === series.name) {
          if (series.visible) {
            series.hide();
          } else {
            series.show()
          }
        }
      })
    }

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  chose()
})
```

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Bastss/daL7nzjr/ . Also, check this Highcharts solution to customize legend when the chart has a lot of series: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/navigation/

Best regards!